# Formatador de datas não esta funcionado

Tags: java, android

Tenho um código que supostamente passa para o formato `dd-mm-yyyy` ou por exemplo `02-10-2017` mas o meu problema é que este código em vez de passar para `02-10-2017` esta a passar para `2-10-2017`.

Código :

```
dt = 2 + "-" + 10 + "-" + 2017;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
try {
    sdf.parse(dt);
    date_text.setText(dt);
    Log.d(tag,""+dt);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

No log tenho este resultado :

```
07-13 20:42:25.914 12020-12020/com.pedrogouveia.averagemaker D/tag: 2-10-2017
```

Código atualizado :

```
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;
            date_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            date_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
            date_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            dt = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            dataInterpetrada = sdf.format(dt);     <---------Esta linha  esta vermelha e esta dizendo incompatible types java.util.dates and java.lang.string 
            dt = sdf.format(dataInterpetrada);
            date_text.setText(dt);

        }
    };
```

Mais em baixo adiciono dt á minha database como string

Comment: Estranho, você escreveu `dt = 2 + "-" + 10 + "-" + 2017;`, mas o log diz `D/tag: 14-7-2017`, será que você não fez alguma confusão?

Comment: Não era so um exemplo o 2-10-2017 o meu tem um dataPicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `parse` do `SimpleDateFormat` devolve a data que foi interpretada.

Logo é suposto ser algo como:

```
Date dataInterpretada = sdf.parse(dt);
```

E se a quiser escrever no `Log` com o formato anterior é necessário usar o `format` do mesmo objeto do formato:

```
Log.d(tag,""+ sdf.format(dataInterpretada ));
```

[Pequeno teste em java para confirmar](http://ideone.com/pNwGJo).

Completando o código apresentado:

```
dt = 2 + "-" + 10 + "-" + 2017;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
try {
    Date dataInterpretada = sdf.parse(dt); //agora guarda a data interpretada
    date_text.setText(sdf.format(dataInterpretada )); //agora com format
    Log.d(tag,""+sdf.format(dataInterpretada )); //e aqui com format também
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit:

O `SimpleDateFormat` devolve uma data do tipo `java.util.date` e não `java.sql.date`.
Para resolver este problema ou troca o `import` ou pode trocar apenas na criação da data fazendo:

```
java.util.Date dataInterpretada = sdf.parse(dt);
```

Comment: Não eu queria mesmo transformar esta data numa string , so que numa string no formato 02-10-2017 , como faço ?

Comment: @PedroGouveia me parece que é exatamente isto que o codigo do Isac faz, transforma em string. Entendeu? O parse converte para um objeto, o correto é usar .format.

Comment: Quando uso .format em vez de .parse , tenho este erro : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.lang.String

Comment: Qual a linha de código onde está a ser utilizado o `format`

Comment: Como voce esta dizendo nao da porque diz que é preciso ser uma string para receber.

Comment: o sdf.parse(dt)

Comment: O `format` devolve a data em formato `String`, logo pode ser utilizada em qualquer lugar que se espera uma `String`. E tem que ter as duas partes. Quando for para interpretar a data usa só `parse`, e quando for para mostrar no `Log` ou noutro sitio usa só `format`

Comment: Eu vou editar com o código que atualizado depois diga me alguma coisa

Comment: Ja editei pode dizer sua opinião por favor ?

Comment: O problema está no `import` o parse devolve um `java.util.date` e não um `java.sql.date`. Ou troca o `import` ou quando recebe a data tem que é indicar que é do tipo `java.util.Date`. Vou editar a resposta para contemplar isso também

Comment: Pai voce me salvou , se pudesse ate te dava 10 certos fodasse, voce para que ? Tu es tuga! é bem ! obrigado